Does the uniformizer $\pi$ generate the extension $K/T$ where $T$ is the inertia field?
I'm trying to prove the equivalence of the statements
(1) $\sigma(x) \equiv x$ mod $\mathfrak{p}^{i+1}$ (that is, $\sigma \in V_i$, the $i^{th}$ ramification group) for all $x\in \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$;
(2) $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi$ mod $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}^{i+1}$.
Above, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of the number field $K$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$, the localisation of this ring at $\mathfrak{p}$ is the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$ with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}=(\pi)$, and $\sigma$ is an element of the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$.
One way to prove this would be to show that every element of $K$ can be written as a polynomial in $\pi$ with coefficients in the inertia field $T$ (the fixed field of the inertia group $I_{\mathfrak{p}}$).
Is this a true statement, and if so, how would one go about proving it?

I'll show how to do this when $K/T$ is a totally ramified extension of local fields, and I'll leave you to figure out how to translate this to the exact statement you've given. The key fact is that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathcal{O}_T[\pi]$ as rings. If you don't know this fact already, you should prove it; the main idea is to prove that the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ is Eisenstein and think about valuations, using the fact that $K/T$ is totally ramified.
Given this, you can write any given element $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_T$ as $\alpha = \sum_{i = 0}^{e - 1} c_i \pi^i$ with $c_i \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and $e$ the degree of the extension. If $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi \bmod \mathfrak{m}^{i + 1}$, then we also have $\sigma(\pi)^i \equiv \pi^i \bmod \mathfrak{m}^{i + 1}$ for any $i \geq 1$, and so
$$\sigma(\alpha) - \alpha = \sum_{i = 0}^{e - 1} c_i (\sigma(\pi)^i - \pi^i) \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak{m}^{i + 1}.$$
This gives the local version of (2) $\implies$ (1), and the local version of (1) $\implies$ (2) is trivial. Note here that it is really important that all of the $c_i$ are integral, which is why we need $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathcal{O}_T[\pi]$ and not just $K = T(\pi)$.
